# How to query the motherboard/mainboard number?

Tags: hardware, ram

I have a PC with a an old AMD Sempron 3000+ processor on which I wanna query the motherboard aka mainboard model number to check which kind of RAM to buy for it.

How do I do this in Ubuntu 11.10?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `sudo lshw`, that should give you back all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a GUI solution, try the package 'hardinfo'

Comment: what does it do? how will it help? how do you get it?